# How can you automate rolling upgrades of Docker Swarm nodes?

Tags: docker, terraform, docker-swarm

What's the typical process to roll out an upgrade of Docker and other OS updates to 
a Docker Swarm cluster?

Since I want it rolled out, I was thinking of just doing a full Terraform build which will contain the latest security patches and upgrades.  The way I am presently doing it is manually taint a set and upgrade accordingly then prune the left over node definitions.

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/trajano/swarm-aws/docker/

The thing is this is still pretty manual, I would like to be able to say "upgrade swarm" and it will do the work for me with minimal downtime.

Answer (score 0):

When using Terraform to create a set of instances with the `aws_instance` resource you will have to keep doing the "taint and apply" method.

If you used an autoscaling group you could use [Bouncer](https://github.com/palantir/bouncer) to roll the members of the autoscaling group.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Watchover](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) for updating containers automatically. I didn't try it on a swarm but it should work.